# Mathematica parallelization error

Tags: parallelization, xact

I am trying to parallelize some code in Mathematica 11.3 under Ubuntu 20.04, but I get the following errors:

[image]

the code is a s follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
<< xAct`xTensor`
<< xAct`xCoba`
DefManifold[M4, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
DefChart[ch, M4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}]
DefScalarFunction[\[CapitalDelta]]
DefScalarFunction[\[Rho]]
DefScalarFunction[M]
DefScalarFunction[A]
DefConstantSymbol[m]
DefConstantSymbol[L]
(*$CVSimplify=Together;*)
M[s_] = (m s^3)/(s^3 + 2 m L^2);
\[Rho][s_, q_] := s^2 + A[s] Cos[q]^2;
\[CapitalDelta][s_] := s^2 - 2 M[s] s + A[s]^2;

met = CTensor[{{-(1 - (2 M[r[]] r[])/\[Rho][r[], \[Theta][]]), 0, 
     0, -2 (A[r[]] M[r[]] r[] Sin[\[Theta][]]^2)/\[Rho][
       r[], \[Theta][]]}, {0, \[Rho][r[], \[Theta][]]/\[CapitalDelta][
      r[]], 0, 0}, {0, 0, \[Rho][r[], \[Theta][]], 
     0}, {-2 (
      A[r[]] M[r[]] r[] Sin[\[Theta][]]^2)/\[Rho][r[], \[Theta][]], 0,
      0, (A[r[]]^2 + r[]^2 + (
        2 A[r[]]^2 M[r[]] r[] Sin[\[Theta][]]^2)/\[Rho][
         r[], \[Theta][]]) Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}}, {-ch, -ch}];
SetCMetric[met, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]
CD = CovDOfMetric[met];
MetricCompute[met, ch, "Einstein"[-1, -1], Parallelize -> True]
```

I do not know whether this is an error in the parallelization or in xAct so I will cross-post in the xAct forum.

Comment: I have tried to use `ParallelTable[{i,2^i},{i,0,30,1}]` and it works perfectly, so it is probably a problem of xAct